# Numba support for pandas dataframe on Mac silicone

Tags: python, pandas, numba

I would like to use the @jitclass decorator however it doesn't support pandas dataframes. Are there any workarounds compatible with Mac silicone?

I tried using https://github.com/IntelPython/sdc but it doesn't seem to work for Mac silicone.

What options do I have....

Comment: The main workaround is simply to extract the Numpy array of the Pandas columns and operate on it. The columns need to have a native (numpy) type (and not be strings).

Comment: Cheers. Datetime is presumably fine?

Comment: AFAIR, there is a support of that in Numba. The last time I tried to used it was working for basic stuff but it was quite experimental. It is worth a try.